# Newer version of QGIS doesn't display hillshade like in older version

Tags: qgis

I use QGIS 2.18 for looking at hillshades. I am trying to migrate to 3.18 but I am finding that the quality of the hillshades generated in the later version are not as detailed as in the older version. I can not find what I am missing. Could someone point me in the right direction to get this working right?

Side by side image comparison with 3.18 on left and 2.18 on right:
[image]

Comment: Default values for raster layer settings may be different in each version. Did you try to play around with layer settings in QGIS 3?

Comment: Indeed, at a quick glance it looks like you might be contrast stretching (to min/max) the display at right and not at left. And perhaps different lighting settings for the hillshade as well, can't tell.

Comment: Check the resampling in the `layer styling panel` for zoomed-im and zoomed-out.

Comment: A re-producible test case would help a lot: a piece of DEM and exact options used with QGIS 2.18 and 3.18.

Comment: Thanks Kadir for getting my screenshot to show in my post. I did try playing around more with it today and found that if I adjusted the Hillshade brightness to about -46 and contrast to 47 in the the Symbology \Color Rendering section I was able to closely replicate what I am used to. on the 2.18 version they where both set to 0. I don't understand why it is working differently but it is.
I did try comparing settings like Houska and Wingnut suggest but couldn't find anything that helped. User30184, this was for different NYS Dem's. I had the same problem across multiple PC's

Comment: I could try to post additional follow up information if anyone wants it. But I think the adjustment of the contrast and brightness will do for now.

I really appreciate the responses from all of you. It was nice to find a knowledgeable group of folks offering their help to someone like me that has barely a clue how to use QGIS for anything other than creating Hillshades.